# GCM get Token for sending notification from server

Tags: android, push-notification, onesignal

I'm using one signal to send notification but I need to send notification for specific users from server. 
I searched for a while but every solution i found was deprecated.

Comment: On April 10, 2018, Google deprecated GCM.

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman you mean it isn't useful anymore ?

Comment: No it is no more usable. Check my answer and follow the official step by step guides to migrate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On April 10, 2018, Google has shut down GCM (Google Cloud Messaging) support. So I strongly recommend that you should migrate your code to FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging).

[Check out this](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/android-migrate-fcm) to migrate GCM to FCM.